# Read CSV file in chunks using generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, iterator, generator

I have a big csv file that I need to process and it's done this way (very simplified):

```
import csv
from csv import excel

def _get_dialect():
    class CustomDialect(excel):
        delimiter = ','
    return CustomDialect()

class DictIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), 
                                     fieldnames=['col1', 'col2'], 
                                     dialect=_get_dialect())

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.reader.__next__()

items = DictIter()
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

There are better ways to do it but that's what I have right now.
Now I would like to split processing into chunks and found this simple solution that should work for me:

```
def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize=500):
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield chunk
            del chunk[:]
        chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk
```

However I'm lacking some generator knowledge to combine these two pieces of code together. Basically I want something like this:

```
import csv
from csv import excel

def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize=500):
    chunk = []
    for i, line in enumerate(reader):
        if (i % chunksize == 0 and i > 0):
            yield chunk
            del chunk[:]
        chunk.append(line)
    yield chunk

def _get_dialect():
    class CustomDialect(excel):
        delimiter = ','
    return CustomDialect()

class DictIter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(open('test.csv'), 
                                     fieldnames=['col1', 'col2'], 
                                     dialect=_get_dialect())

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for chunk in gen_chunks(self.reader):
            for item in chunk:
                yield item

items = DictIter()
for item in items:
    print(item)
```

It might be somewhat clumsy approach but I want to implement splitting processing with minimal changes to the current structure. What I'm trying to achieve is leave the current implementation with iterator class but process one chunk at a time and yield the next chunk when I'm done with the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks like an overly complicated way of doing:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['col1', 'col2'])
    for item in reader:
        print(item)
```

Your chunking still returns one item at a time.  The default delimiter of the `excel` dialect is comma, and `excel` is the default dialect.

Note `newline=''` is the documented way of opening the file passed to a `csv` reader or writer object.

If you have a real reason for chunking (multiprocessing?) you should state that and show *that* attempt if it doesn't work.

Comment: My current code is an overly complicated because that class has a lot of other things that are not shown here for simplification and should stay as an iterator class.

My reason for chunking is that some of csv files are very big and the server has limited RAM so I wanted to process file in chunks. After file is read there are a lot of data filtering and transformation happening that eats resources.

What I'm trying to achieve is leave the current implementation with iterator class but process one chunk at a time and yield the next chunk when I'm done with the previous one.

Comment: @NST What's the difference between reading 500 lines and processing them as a list one at a time vs. processing them one at a time?  It's using *more* ram to read in 500 lines than one at a time...the OS is caching the file reads for you anyway.  This looks like a case of premature "optimization". Make sure to measure...

Comment: @MarkTolonen I don't think your answer cover the chunk part ! specially in the last line you are questioning the purpose of the question !! I feel this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: @user702846 It doesn’t need to. Chunking was pointless for a single process. The OP was overly complicating the issue.